# Call self.variable(established in __init__() ) within class definition parameters

Tags: python, class

I would like to call a class variable established in **init** from a class definition so it can be the default parameter value. Wording is hard but here is an example.

```
class Sound:
   def __init__(self):
      self.volume = 10

   def set_volume(self, vol=self.volume)
      play_sound_a(vol)
```

I assumed that since **init** is called, then I should be able to use variables established in **init** from class definitions. I could do some if statements within the definition but using parameter defaults would be easier.

I simply get an error that self does not exist.

Comment: Default parameters to a function are evaluated *once*, when the function was originally defined.  In the case of a method, this is during the evaluation of the class body: the class doesn't even exist yet, and there are certainly no instances of the class yet, so there is nothing that `self` could conceivably refer to.  The usual solution here is to use `None` (or some such distinct value) as the default, then say `if vol is None: vol = self.volume` in the method.

Comment: Agree with @jasonharper - if your default value is anything more than a simple constant, then use `None` (or similar) in the definition and then assign it inside the function code itself.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done this way. The default parameter is defined when the method is compiled, well before any instance has been created. In fact, all instances of that class will share that same default value for that method. Instead you can use a sentinel such as `None` to know when you should use the instance volume. Assuming `None` is not otherwise a valid value for that parameter.

```
class Sound:
    def __init__(self):
        self.volume = 10

    def set_volume(self, vol=None):
        if vol is None:
            vol = self.volumne
        play_sound_a(vol)
```